# Use the current insert id as a field value of another column in one sql request

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I intend to perform the following in just one sql request

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (col2,col3,col4) VALUES('a','b',current_insert_id());
```

But current_insert_id() seems to be not implemented.

Attempts:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (col2, col3, col4) VALUES('a','b',last_insert_id());
```

it gives me 0 on the last field

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (col2, col3, col4) VALUES('a','b','dummy_value');
UPDATE TABLE1 SET col4=LAST_INSERT_ID() WHERE ID=LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

but this uses 2 queries.

Comment: You can't do this in one query AFAIK.  But, since you have the `id` column which contains the actual auto increment value anyway, why can't you just use that column instead of `col4`?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Intend to use the first insert as the Group ID of a multi query application procedure. So its like, one application request will initiate multiple inserts. And I want to track who belongs to to which application request. I dont plan to create a new table just for this group cause its not that critical.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 
    (col2,col3,col4)
VALUES
    (
      'a',
      'b',
      (
        SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT 
        FROM information_schema.TABLES 
        WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = "YOUR_DB_NAME" 
        AND TABLE_NAME = "TABLE1"
      )
    );
```

Don't do it in production though. It's not nice :)

Comment: Why is it not nice? Is this prone to race conditions? like when there are a lot of concurrent query to the database?

Comment: I'm not sure of how it behaves with transactions etc, but for production, the best and standard way of doing this is your 2nd method with the 2 queries wrapped in a transaction.